# issue at running xamarin on visual studio 2015 "Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK"

Tags: java, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, java-8

I try to install visual studio 2015 with xamarin by these following step

1. install VS 2015 for mobile application

   2. install Java JDK 8 for both version 64 & 86
   3. update android SDK to be V26

But I am still have issue , visual studio couldn't see java SDK with populate this error at running "Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK" although try these following items to fix this issue.

1. install JDK 8 for 64 , 86
2. add **JAVA_HOME** at Environment variable at windows as following snapshot (Java_Home Config)

   [image: [1]]
3. add **JAVA BIN path** to Path environment variable at windows as following snapshot (Path config)

   [image: [2]]
4. make sure Java JDK is defined at Xamarin configuration

Answer (score 0):

> Could not locate **Java 6 or 7 SDK**.

You have Java 8. Android does not (yet) fully support Java 8.

Also, why do you have 32bit and 64bit java in your path? You only need `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in the path.

Comment: hi cricket_007, i do what you recomeend , i download JAVA 7 and updata JAVA_HOME , PATH and XAMARIN config without any change.

Comment: Any luck on resolving this issue?  Running into same here.

Comment: @Klaus If you have a new question, please create a new post

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for `Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK`.

After 2 days of a hard battle with Visual Studio 2015 Community, this solution was found:

First, You need to download and install Java SE Development Kit 7 from oracle archives (an account needed to download package). In my case I downloaded 32 bit version.

If You don't have Android NDK, download it from Android web page (Check if NDK is set in Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings).

After those steps restart Visual Studio.

VS should automatically find java jdk path. You can check it in Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings.
If Android NDK location is not found, then provide the path to te package you downloaded from Android website.

**The last and key step is to go to Build and choose Clean solution.**

After that you can try to build your solution and it should works like a charm.